# The pronunciation of Burns' "I wad gie a' Knockhaspie's land"

Tags: pronunciation, scottish-english

> I wad gie a' Knockhaspie's land
>   *([Highland Harry Back Again](http://www.robertburns.org/works/284.shtml))*

What is the best way to phoneticize this sentence?

/aɪ ˈwɑ(ː **?**)d ɡi(ː **?**) **???** lɑn/

Comment: A place name in Burns text -- if you've got no idea how it's pronounced then you have no idea how it's pronounced.

Comment: @HotLicks sorry... what?

Comment: The pronunciation of Scottish place names/surnames is often nowhere near what you would expect from the spelling.

Comment: @HotLicks oh, yes! That's why I'm here.

Comment: You should ask Knockhaspie because only the holder of a name knows the correct way to pronounce it. For example you might assume that someone with the name "Menzies" should be called "Mingis" but you could be wrong.

Comment: @WeatherVane the best person to ask could be R. Burns but, unfortunately, he's dead and hence I ask linguists or literary scholars for help. Moreover, there is no possibility to ask 'the holder of a name' who lived in the 18th century.

Comment: The chorus is from an old song, the hero of which, according to Mr. Peter Buchan, was a Harry Lumsdale, associated with a daughter of the laird of Knockhaspie. [Wiki](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Book_of_Scottish_Song/Highland_Harry).

Comment: I've camped in [Portknockie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portknockie)  but Knockhaspie seems not to exist as a place.

Comment: @WeatherVane Hopefully someone can [hear the recording from BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sounds/play/p03zrd25) but I unfortunately cannot given that "This content is not available at your location".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with most other languages, there are many dialects of Scots and Burns was using his own literary version for an English-speaking audience, so it is difficult to be precise. He was making an attempt at representing the sound phonetically, so read it as written as much as you can. But here are some comments:

Firstly, the poem is mostly in [Iambic Tetrameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iambic_tetrameter) (da DUM da DUM da DUM da DUM) so that tells us where the stress is.

> [I](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/a_pers_pron) [wad](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/wad_v2) [gie](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/gie_v1) [a'](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/a_adj_adv) [Knock](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/knock_n3)haspie's [land](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/land)
>
> /ə 'wɤd giː 'ɒː nɔk'hæspɪz 'lɑn/
>
> I would give all Knockhaspie's land

It follows that the first word, *I* is unstressed. Its pronunciation depends on whether it is stressed, although it is usually spelt *A*. Unstressed it is pronounced /ə/.

Knockhaspie may or may not be a real name but it is a regularly formed anglicized Gaelic name. *Knock* means hill and so is unstressed. Haspie could be a Gaelic personal name beginning with *s* which would change to *h* in the genitive and the stress would be on the first syllable of *haspie*, which fits the metre. So Knockhaspie would be *Cnoc Sheasbaidh* /knɔʰk ˈhæspɪ/ which would mean "Saspadh's Hill" /ˈsæspəɣ/. *Knock* is unambiguous, but I am only speculating about the second element.